# JQUeryUI Dialog and HTML select

Tags: jquery, select, user-interface

I have an ASPX page where jQuery UI dialog will appear on the screen ,on clicking on a button,When the UI dialog is active ,User cant interact with any other controls.ITs working good. But I have a Dropdown list (Select ) in the page .It is still active .User is able to go and choose any option from the dropdown. I know that in IE6,Its considering select box as a new element.
How can i solve this ? I want to restict users from changing the dropdownlist content when UI Dialog is active

Any thoughts ?   Thanks in advance

Edit
My Style tage inside the head

```
<style type="text/css">
    body { font-size: 62.5%; }
    label, input { display:block;
        width: 94px;
    }
    input.text { margin-bottom:12px; width:95%; padding: .4em; }
    fieldset { padding:0; border:0; margin-top:25px; }
    h1 { font-size: 1.2em; margin: .6em 0; }
    div#users-contain {  width: 350px; margin: 20px 0; }
    div#users-contain table { margin: 1em 0; border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; }
    div#users-contain table td, div#users-contain table th { border: 1px solid #eee; padding: .6em 10px; text-align: left; }
    .ui-button { outline: 0; margin:0; padding: .4em 1em .5em; text-decoration:none;  !important; cursor:pointer; position: relative; text-align: center; }
    .ui-dialog .ui-state-highlight, .ui-dialog .ui-state-error { padding: .3em;  }
    #dialog{
     display: none;
    }


</style>
```

and i am using the dialog.open method to show the dialog

```
 $("#dialog").dialog("open");
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the following example:

http://jsbin.com/ibeje

I cannot replicate what's happening. There's something else going on. Are you setting the z-order of the select box yourself?

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing the same thing currently with IE6. My aspx page has several html selects and they show through the jQuery UI 1.7.1 dialog box that appears over them. I believe this is happening because the dialog is not placing a hidden/zero opacity **iFrame under the dialog.** I would kinda expect that UI developers would have done this already for us IE6 guys, but there it is.

When I find a convenient fix for this I will post it or if some other kind soul could do so that would be great.

The link **altCognito** submitted also has this problem in IE6 too.

This page references the iframe fix but it not specifically for UI Dialog: 
ht tp://stackoverflow.com/questions/7937/solve-the-ie-select-overlap-bug

Sorry Im a new user and new users are not allowed to post working hyperlinks

Addtionally, are you using:

$('.selector').dialog({ modal: true });

To make your dialog modal and block interaction with the parent page?

Answer (score 0):

on the dialog you need to set bgiframe : true and also include the bgiframe plugin

[see here](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog#option-bgifr)